# d3.request generates unauthorized error

Tags: d3.js

I am using d3.request.js to download data from a remote server which requires HTTP Basic Authentication. My scripts are:

```js
var query="<request-url>";
d3.request(query)
    .post()
    .user("login-id")
    .password("login-password")
    .get(function(error, data) {
      //scripts to process result
      }
     )
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-request.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

However upon executing the above scripts, I received 401 (Unauthorized) error. I have tested to use $.ajax request method before switching to d3.request. And it was working. Hence it should not be the cross domain issue from the remote server. The result is a json object, I tested using d3.json which also failed.

Any suggestion for this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: As a side note not intended to solve your problem: the module d3-request is included in the minified full version of D3 v4. There is no need to include the standalone module script.

Comment: Thanks, will exclude the library. Just to update my question, it is connecting to a https server.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a cross-origin request?  My WAG is that [this is your problem](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/1397).  Try this:

```
var query="<request-url>";
d3.request(query)
  .post()
  .user("login-id")
  .password("login-password")
  .on("beforesend", function(request) { request.withCredentials = true; })
  .get(function(error, data) {
    //scripts to process result
   }
 );
```

Comment: It shouldn't be the cross domain issue since it does work when I use Ajax request.

Comment: @chen, is it cross-origin?  Perhaps `$.ajax` is setting `.withCredentials` for you....  How are you calling `$.ajax`?

Comment: Mark, I am using the following scripts for ajax call 
`$.ajax
`  ({
   `type: "POST",
  `url: query_string,
   `async: false,`
   `headers: {
    `"Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD)
   `},
   `success: function (data){
   `},
   `error: function(error) {
   `}
  `});

Answer (score 0):

The following scripts turned out to solve my issues.

```js
 d3.json(query)
  .header("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD))
  .get(function(error, data) {
   if(error) {
    console.log(error);
   }else{
    console.log(data);      }
  });
```

Thanks for your time.